Editable diff of changes in VS Code?
I'm using VS Code and Im trying to recreate a feature that I miss from WebStorm.
Is there a way of seeing a diff all changes from a certain reference (eg the main branch) and also be able to edit files in that view?
From the control panel I can go:
GitLense: Compare References... > main > head
This does show me the changes but the view is read only.
